# Multiple retrofit2 requests merged on hashmap with rxJava2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a list of objects: `ArrayList<T> arrayList;` and on every object of the list there is an Id: `T.getId()` whom I need for making a request. As a response another list of objects is fetched: `ArrayList<E> anotherList`

I want to make multiple calls based on the id: `T.getId()` and on every response I want to merge that Object: `T` with the response: `ArrayList<E> anotherList` on a hashmap: `Hashmap<T, ArrayList<E> anotherList>` and return the value after all requests has been finished. Is there a way i can achieve this using `rxJava`?:

```
//For every `T.getId()`, fetch `ArrayList<E> anotherList` 
for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
    T object = arrayList.get(i);
    fetchData(T.getId());
}
```

on every `onNext()` merge(hashmap.put()) `T` with response `ArrayList<E> anotherList` on `Hashmap<T, ArrayList<E> anotherList>`. After all requests finished return final `hashmap` containing those pairs:

```
retrofit.fetchData(T.getId())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(...)
        .merge(...)
        .subscribeWith(...)
```

Is there a way i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a field :
`private HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<E>> mHashMap;`

Once this field was instanciate , you can try :

```
Observable.just(arrayList)
                .flatMapIterable(new Function<ArrayList<T>, Iterable<? extends T>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<? extends T> apply(ArrayList<T> ts) throws Exception {
                        return ts;
                    }
                }).flatMap(new Function<T, ObservableSource<Hashmap<T,ArrayList<E>>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<Hashmap<T,ArrayList<E>>> apply(T t) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Hashmap<T,ArrayList<E>>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Hashmap<T,ArrayList<E>> call() throws Exception {
                                mHashMap.put(t, fetchData(t.getId()));
                                return mHashMap;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

`flatMapIterable` it's use to get each item of the `arrayList` and `flatMap` allows you to use each item to create a associated observable of that you need.

Then use a DisposableObserver to get on the `onNext` callback the intermediate completed `HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<E>>` and on the `onCompleted` callback the fully completed `HashMap`

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.